# mmap() returns EINVAL

Tags: c, mmap

I can't get the **mmap** function to work. It returns the *EINVAL* error code.

```
void* mapped = 
        mmap((void*)(map_addr + slide),
             map_size,
             PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ,
             MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON,
             bprm->file,
             map_offset);
```

I've checked the documentation for this function on my platform (**Darwin**) and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. The man page for mmap presents four cases under which EINVAL would be returned.

```
 [EINVAL]           MAP_FIXED was specified and the addr argument was not page
                    aligned, or part of the desired address space resides out of the
                    valid address space for a user process.
```

MAP_FIXED isn't specified so it isn't this.

```
 [EINVAL]           flags does not include either MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED.
```

MAP_PRIVATE is present.

```
 [EINVAL]           The len argument was negative.
```

The len (map_size) argument at the time of the call is 8192.

```
 [EINVAL]           The offset argument was not page-aligned based on the page size as
                    returned by getpagesize(3).
```

The offset argument (map_offset) is 0 so it must be page aligned. (maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: With MAP_ANON, some implementation require the fd to be -1. May be worth checking.

Comment: **@Simon Elliott** Yes, you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about your reading of the first description? It could also be read as describing two disjoint cases:

1. MAP_FIXED was specified and the addr argument was not page aligned,
2. or part of the desired address space resides out of the valid address space for a user process.

if read like this, the actual value of the the `map_addr + slide` expression becomes interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `NULL` for the `addr` argument and giving the implementation the complete freedom to place your `mmaped` region( cos the address you specify might go awry with respect to the process' address space) until there's a serious reason not to do otherwise.

Comment: As a test, I've tried using `NULL`. Still returning `EINVAL`.

Comment: @NickBrooks Can you test the PAGE_SIZE on your system?